# Using fastmail on Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

My fastmail account messages are often garbled text such as this:DQo8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD4NCjxodG1sPg0KPGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29u dGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgiIC8+PG1ldGEg bmFtZT0idmlld3BvcnQiIGNvbnRlbnQ9ImluaXRpYWwtc2NhbGU9MS4wIiAvPjxtZXRhIG5h bWU9ImZvcm1hdC1kZXRlY3Rpb24iIGNvbnRlbnQ9InRlbGVwaG9uZT1ubyIgLz48dGl0bGU+ 
which go on for pages. Occasionally I will get a message from a company and I can tell from the links which company it has come from but the header tells me its has come from someone else, e.g. The links suggest the content is from Pinterest and the headers says it has come from Amazon or Ebay
n; overflow:hidden; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; height:0px;">=
=0A                Hi Alan, We have new jobs for you, including t=
his =0A            =0A        =0A        =0A       =
    =0A                =0A     =
          =0A=0A =
                  =0A                    =0A                        =0A =
                          =
=0A                                https://www.totaljo=
bs.com/JobSearch/EmailLink.aspx?ReturnUrl=3Dhttps%3a%2f%2f
www.totaljobs.com%3fDCMP%3dR_EM_JBE_TJ_AUT_JBE2_070420_T8SD&GUID=3D8=
215f0193f7f4999a36cd36dff1da9de&domain=3Dfastmail.fm&
batchinstanceid=3Df0f10517-d923-4523-b4ba-d463ad903e96&umid=3D202=
This overwrote an existing email (I can no longer read) from the Japan Centre
00407120244-026839The messages are fine when I use the fastmail app on my phone

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.